# Dark Side Of The Moon REDUX

Tags: pink-floyd

As we are all aware, Roger Waters is releasing a new version of `Dark Side Of The Moon`. The album itself is brilliant on one hundred different levels. It is a true work of art that has evidently lived across generations, still considered to be one of if not the best album of all time.

I tried to listen to the new version of Money which is originally on B side of the album (6th track) and it is good, very different from the original though.

Lot's of people are critiquing this "redux" as Roger called it but I honestly can't find anything wrong with this.

What do you think? Are these critics politically charged because of Rogers' views?